# why but line this is not displayed. PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, draw

the code is made in the PIl library under python
I just want that but line can be displayed

I did a test to see if the lines appeared but they are not why

```
import sys
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from PIL import Image
import random

w, h = 800, 800
im = Image.new("RGB", (w, h), "black")

for _ in range(10_00):
    im.putpixel((random.randrange(800), random.randrange(800)), (255, 255, 255))

im.save("test.png")
```

the part above is to create the image with random pixels this part works but the one below sensing drawing lines does not work

```
with Image.open("test.png") as im:

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    draw.line((0, 0) + im.size, fill=128) #pas de ligne dessiné au lancement
    draw.line((0, im.size[1], im.size[0], 0), fill=128)




im.save(sys.stdout, "PNG")
mon_image = Image.open("test.png")
mon_image.show()
```

I don't know what to try

Comment: `10_00` is a strange way (although not incorrect) so group zeros. Usually they are grouped in packs of 3.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the issuing line.

`im.save(sys.stdout, "PNG")`

The first parameter `fp` is filename, path or file object.

> param fp: A filename (string), pathlib.Path object or file object.

You can just save with original file name.

```
im.save('test.png')
```